# Can we use multiple this bindings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

A small example

```js
function speak(line){
  console.log(`The ${this.type} rabbit says '${line}' you ${this.type}`);
}

let whiteRabbit = {type: "white", speak, type: "bad"};

whiteRabbit.speak("OH my dear" + " how you smell ");
```

Output is unexpected

```
The bad rabbit says 'OH my dear how you smell ' you bad
```

Why did it not return The white rabbit?

I created new object

```
let whiteRabbit2 = {type: "white", speak, type2: "bad"}
```

Then I have

```
The white rabbit says 'OH my dear how you smell ' you white
```

I wanted `you bad`.
Solved with slight function change

```
 function speak(line){
... console.log(`The ${this.type} rabbit says '${line}' you ${this.type2}`);
... }
```

Comment: Did you look at what's actually in `whiteRabbit`? Also, could you use a more neutral example?

Comment: Such question example might condemn you to the blue pill. Forever. Please, be polite.

Comment: no, objects can't have multiple values at the same key, let alone guess which one of the values you want to use. Why not just have two different keys?

Comment: The title doesn't match the content, which does not appear to be about multiple *this* bindings.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you expected the output you expected, or what problem you're trying to solve.  Perhaps you could elaborate on the goal with this?

Comment: If you duplicate members, the last value will be taken. Now suppose you want to display `whiteRabbit.type`. How would it be possible to differenciate which types you're requesting ? Duplicates properties makes no sense

Comment: @Cid Thanks for help. Type2 does not hep either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
  type: "white",
  speak,
  type: "as***le", // <- overrides the `type` key. now it's not white but "as***le"
}
```

the final object is

```js
{
  type: "as***le",
  speak: "somevalue of the speak var",
}
```

---

it is the same as with an array

```js
var a = [1, 2, 5];
a[2] = 2; // overrides the value, doesn't add it.
a[1] = 3; // overrides the value, doesn't add it.

// [1, 3, 2]
```

---

Therefore - simply rename the property to `type1` for example or use a stack of values.